# Eager loading given the db ref

Tags: php, mongodb, php-mongodb

```
$posts = $collection->find();
```

How should I eager load the categories each post is referenced to?

```
//1 Document from $posts
{
   "_id": ObjectId("502803b6d4ebdfd805000032"),
   "title": "abcd",
   "message": "abc",
   "category": {
     "$ref": "categories",
     "$id": ObjectId("5027e15dd4ebdfd80500001e") 
  }
}

//the document in categories referenced from the post above
{
   "_id": ObjectId("5027e15dd4ebdfd80500001e"),
   "name": "miscellaneous",
   "slug": "miscellaneous",
   "description": "",
   "created_at": ISODate("2012-08-12T17: 01: 17.0Z"),
   "updated_at": ISODate("2012-08-12T19: 27: 50.0Z") 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mongo has no server side "eager" loading.

As such to load related records iterate through the posts cursor and manually query for the related document.

Do not worry about the whole "lazy" loading thing, it is fine with Mongo.

If you wanna take the strain off the server a little because of various unknown situations then you can iterate all the way through the posts you need gathering an array of `_id`'s to use and then all in one query get those categories back out and sorting them as needed.

If I am honest, DBRefs are not what you think they are and actually are rarely needed in Mongo. Normally a `ObjectId` relating to the other row will do just fine.

All DBRefs really do is provide an object by which to make it easier and simpler to get the related record: http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongodbref.php and is only really useful when you DON'T already know the collection. Think of it as a self describing ID to many related collections.